Parsing extended lambda calculus using recursive descent
I'm writing interpreter for simple lambda calculus based language in C. EBNF for language is
S ::= E
E ::= 'fn' var '->' E | T {'+' T} | T {'-' T}
T ::= F {'*' F} | F {'/' F}
F ::= P {P}
P ::= var | number | '(' E ')'

I've already written parser for same grammar but without 4-th production rule. But how I could deal with {P}?
Of course, I can just check lookahead token, and if it's var, number or '(' then call procedure for parsing P (say parse_primitive), but in this case I will have same extra check of lookahead in parse_primitive, so i definitely doing something wrong.
EDIT: my code now looks like this:
Ast *parse_expr(Lexer *lexer) {
  if (match_token(lexer, TOK_KW_FN) {
    expect_token(lexer, TOK_VAR);
    char *lexeme = get_last_lexeme(lexer);
    Ast *var = make_var(lexeme);
    expect_token(lexer, TOK_ARROW);
    Ast *body = parse_expr(lexer);
    return make_ast(var, body);
  } else {
    Ast *expr = parse_term(lexer);
    for (;;) {
      int op;
      if (match_token(lexer, TOK_PLUS)) {
        op = OP_ADD;
      } else if (match_token(lexer, TOK_MINUS)) {
        op = OP_SUB;
      } else {
        return expr;
      }
      Ast *term = parse_term(lexer);
      expr = make_binop(op, expr, term);
    }
  }
}

Ast *parse_term(Lexer *lexer) {
  Ast *term = parse_factor(lexer);
  for (;;) {
    int op;
    if (match_token(lexer, TOK_STAR)) {
      op = OP_MUL;
    } else if (match_token(lexer, TOK_SLASH)) {
      op = OP_DIV;
    } else {
      return term;
    }
    Ast *factor = parse_factor(lexer);
    term = make_binop(op, term, factor);
  }
}

Ast *parse_factor(Lexer *lexer) {
  Ast *factor = parse_primitive(lexer);
  for (;;) {
    int tok = lexer_peek(lexer);
    if (tok != TOK_LPAR && tok != TOK_VAR && tok != TOK_NUMBER) { /* i want to remove this check as if is actually done by parse_primitive */
      return factor;
    }
    Ast *primitive= parse_primitive(lexer);
    factor = make_app(factor, primitive);
  }
}

Ast *parse_primitive(Lexer *lexer) {
  if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_LPAR)) {
    Ast *expr = parse_expr(lexer);
    if (!lexer_match(lexer, TOK_RPAR)) {
      parser_error("expected ')'");
    }
    return expr;
  } else if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_NUMBER)) {
    char *lexeme = get_last_lexeme(lexer);
    return make_number(lexeme);
  } else if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_VAR)) {
    char *lexeme = get_last_lexeme(lexer);
    return make_var(lexeme);
  }
  parser_error("expected '(', number or var");
}


It's not clear to me what problem you are having with this. The grammar looks unambiguous to me, so I think you should be able to parse it with recursive descent.

@500-InternalServerError But how i can check if i should return from F or should parse P?

As I understand, i should call parse_primitive, and if it fails, then i understand that there's no more application and i should return. But parse_primitive should report an error if it cannot match, so i can't understand what behaviour of parse_primitive should be

"But parse_primitive should report an error": no it shouldn't. It is for the caller to decide what should happen if it fails.

@trincot ok, but if I make all my parsing procedures returning for example NULL on failure, then how error reporting will work? Obviously, I can just call parse_expr and if its result is NULL, print some error message, but how I can understand at that time, where exactly error happened?

You can return an error object that has all the info you need. The caller then decides whether there are other options or not. If not, it returns the same error object. If there are other options, it ignores the error object and tries those.

@trincot thanks, I think I will use this approach, but maybe you can recommend some literature about writing recursive descent parsers in C with good error hendling? Because all literature what i found offers only aproach with double checking of lookahead

It depends on whether you will use backtracking or will use a fixed size look-ahead. I described backtracking. If you want the look-ahead, then in this case I guess you need a look-ahead of at least 3 characters so you can distinguish whether "fn" is the reserved keyword or are the first two letters of a var (like "fname"). So that would be a LL(3) grammar.

You could make this question more focused by providing the relevant code, how to reproduce the issue (with your attempt), and clarify what number and var are. Does number allow -1.34E+103? Does var allow underscores, dollar-symbols, ...etc?

@trincot I want to use 1 token lookahead, i suppose provided grammar is LL(1). These 'fn', number, var, '->' are all different tokens, i have lexer to distinguish them. I've added code, hope it makes my question more clearer

You could add an argument to parse_primitive to indicate whether the primitive is required or is optional. In case it is optional, don't raise an error when it is not matched, but return NULL:
Ast *parse_primitive(Lexer *lexer, int mandatory) {
  if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_LPAR)) {
    Ast *expr = parse_expr(lexer);
    if (!lexer_match(lexer, TOK_RPAR)) {
      // Here we unconditionally raise an error, as the opening bracket
      //    made the closing bracket mandatory.
      parser_error("expected ')'");
    }
    return expr;
  } else if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_NUMBER)) {
    char *lexeme = get_last_lexeme(lexer);
    return make_number(lexeme);
  } else if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_VAR)) {
    char *lexeme = get_last_lexeme(lexer);
    return make_var(lexeme);
  }
  // Conditionally raise an error
  if (mandatory) {
    parser_error("expected '(', number or var");
  }
  return NULL;
}

Now your parse_factor function can look like this:
Ast *parse_factor(Lexer *lexer) {
  Ast *factor = parse_primitive(lexer, 1); // Mandatory
  for (;;) {
    Ast *primitive = parse_primitive(lexer, 0); // Not mandatory
    if (!primitive) {
      return factor;
    }
    factor = make_app(factor, primitive);
  }
}

Without extra parameter?
...then create two versions of the function:
Ast *parse_if_primitive(Lexer *lexer) {
  if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_LPAR)) {
    Ast *expr = parse_expr(lexer);
    if (!lexer_match(lexer, TOK_RPAR)) {
      parser_error("expected ')'");
    }
    return expr;
  } else if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_NUMBER)) {
    char *lexeme = get_last_lexeme(lexer);
    return make_number(lexeme);
  } else if (lexer_match(lexer, TOK_VAR)) {
    char *lexeme = get_last_lexeme(lexer);
    return make_var(lexeme);
  }
  return NULL; // No primitive here
}

Ast *parse_primitive(Lexer *lexer) {
  Ast *primitive = parse_if_primitive(lexer);
  if (!primitive) {
    parser_error("expected '(', number or var");
  }
  return primitive;
}

And call the one you need:
Ast *parse_factor(Lexer *lexer) {
  Ast *factor = parse_primitive(lexer); // Mandatory
  for (;;) {
    Ast *primitive = parse_if_primitive(lexer); // Not mandatory
    if (!primitive) {
      return factor;
    }
    factor = make_app(factor, primitive);
  }
}


Yeah, I can do this way, but then all my parsing procedures looks unconsistent, this additional parameter is needed only for parse_primitive, but not for other procedures. Is there any consistent approach?

Then create two functions: parse_first_primitive and parse_optional_primitive?

Added a section to my answer with that variation.

thanks, but i just intrested: what is so special about this production from theoretical point of view? why other productions do not need two versions but parse_primitive needs?

It is because there is both P and {P}, a situation which does not occur with any other rules (where the same rule can be mandatory or optional without any prefixed separator symbol). For instance, in {'+' T} the T is not optional once you have read the +, so there is no function needed where T could be matched optionally.

thanks, i see. maybe you also know how LL(1) parsers generators usually deal with such cases?

They look ahead and decide on the next symbol which rule to apply. For that your rules must be split into separate rules when they have alternates (|). So like T ::= F {'*' F} | F {'/' F} becomes 1. T ::= F {M}, 2. M ::= '*' F and 3. M ::= '/' F, where they get a unique rule number to identify them. Then create an LL(1) parsing table. With this table and the look-ahead token you can deterministically decide how to proceed. See Wikipedia LL parser -- Set up.

Thank you for your answers! So they actually perform same checks of lookahead multiple times? As understand, in my case grammar looks like this F ::= P L, L ::= eps, L ::= P L, so firstly parser will check if it can apply production L ::= P L, and afer that another check to decide what to apply: P ::= '(' E ')', P ::= var or P ::= number. Am I understand correctly?

For the specific case of P, the rule could be split into 1.  F ::= P Q, 2.  Q ::= P Q, 3. Q ::= ε, where the last rule shows the particularity: it is a catch-all where no other rule for Q matches, and it doesn't consume any input itself.

Yes, you got it right (we posted in parallel).
